# A difficult functional series (still unsolved)

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, trigonometric-series

The problem is to prove if the following functional series converges or not and in the affirmative case to find its sum

$$\qquad\qquad\ \sin^2(\pi x) \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2\sin^2(\frac{\pi x}{k})}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{\sin^2(\pi x)}{k^2\sin^2(\frac{\pi x}{k})}\qquad\ \text{with}\quad x,k\in\Bbb N-\{0\}$$

The denominator of the series, upon which the summation variable acts, can be rewritten in many ways, as follows, none of which have seemed to be useful to solve the problem:

$$\frac{1}{k^2\sin^2(\frac{\pi x}{k})}=\frac{1}{(\pi x)^2\operatorname{sinc}^2(\frac{\pi x}{k})}=\frac{\csc^2(\frac{\pi x}{k})}{k^2}=\frac{1+\cot^2(\frac{\pi x}{k})}{k^2}=\frac{2}{k^2(1-\cos(\frac{2\pi x}{k}))}=\frac{1}{2k^2(1+\cos(\frac{\pi x}{k}))}+\frac{1}{2k^2(1-\cos(\frac{\pi x}{k}))}$$
where
$$ \csc(x)=\frac{1}{\sin(x)}\quad\text{and}\quad \operatorname{sinc}(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$

Also

$$\frac{1}{k^2\sin^2(\frac{\pi x}{k})}=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty  \frac{1}{(x-mk)^2}=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty  \frac{1}{(x+mk)^2}$$

since

$$\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)}=\csc^2(x)=\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{(x-m\pi)^2}=\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{(x+m\pi)^2}$$

Maybe it should be worth noting that the series considered resembles in some way the so called Flint Hills Series (that, differently from the one considered, is a numerical series: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FlintHillsSeries.html) for which, unto this day, it is not known whether it converges or not.

Note:

It is obvious that the result is always $0$, and hence trivial, if the function is evaluated before performing the sum, but this is not what is intended in this case.

In fact, for example, the value resulting for $x=10$ after that the summation of

$$\sum_{k=1}^N  \frac{\sin^2(\pi x)}{k^2\sin^2(\frac{\pi x}{k})}\qquad\ \text{with}\quad x,k,N\in\Bbb N-\{0\}$$

has been performed up to $N\geqslant x=10$ is, and will always be (meaning that it stands for $N \to \infty$), $4$.

Summarizing, it can be easily verified (for convenience with a software like Maple, for example) that

$$\forall\alpha\in\Bbb N-\{0\}\qquad\lim_{x\to\alpha}\Biggl(\sum_{k=1}^{N\geqslant \alpha}  \frac{\sin^2(\pi x)}{k^2\sin^2(\frac{\pi x}{k})}\Biggr)=\beta\neq0\qquad\ \text{with}\quad \beta\in\Bbb N-\{0\}$$
where, clearly, this is one of those cases in which the operation of limit and summation cannot be interchanged.
Another example, but that can be carried out by hand:

$$\lim_{x\to 2}\Biggl(\sum_{k=1}^2\frac{\sin^2(\pi x)}{k^2\sin^2(\frac{\pi x}{k})}\Biggr)=\lim_{x\to 2}\Biggl(1+\frac{\sin^2(\pi x)}{2(1-\cos(\pi x))}\Biggr)=2\neq0$$

So, from the calculations of the partial sums up to an arbitrary extent is evident that, numerically, the summation converge (pointwise?); the problem is to see if it is possible to find, first, an analytical closed form for the summation.

Answer (score 4):

Since $\sin(\pi x/k) \sim \pi x/k$ as $k \to \infty$, the summand has nonzero limit $1/(\pi^2 x^2)$, and the series diverges.

Comment: In the rush, I forgot a factor, the functional series is actually:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{sin^2(\pi x)}{k^2sin^2(\frac{\pi x}{k})}\qquad\ \text{with}\quad x,k\in\Bbb N-\{0\}$$
Now, in the correct expression, the limit of the summand as $k \to \infty $ is

$$ \frac{sin^2(\pi x)}{(\pi x)^2} $$

that is always $0$ for the domain of definition established: $x\in\Bbb N-\{0\}$.

Can you please address my question now?

Comment: Now it's completely trivial: every term  is $0$.

Comment: Dear Sir,
my reply to your answer was too long to be contained within the number of characters allowed by the site for a comment. For this reason, I added a clarification note at the end of my question that address your last remark and I’ll be glad if you would like to take it in consideration.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ah, I see: if $k$ divides $x$ the denominator is $0$ as well.  That means the term is undefined: you can't have $0/0$.  So maybe what you really want is
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lim_{t \to x} \frac{\sin^2(\pi t)}{k^2 \sin^2(\pi t/k)}$$

Comment: If $k$ divides $x$, $$\lim_{t \to x} \frac{\sin^2(\pi t)}{k^2 \sin^2(\pi t/k)} = 1$$  If $k$ does not divide $x$, the limit is $0$.  So that sum would just be the number of (positive integer) divisors of $x$.

Comment: I agree with your last comment (but it doesn’t solve the problem of finding the sum or proving its non-convergence) but not with your second-last.

Even if evaluating the generic addend, given by the function for an arbitrary $x$, once $k$ is established first, may require to operate a limit rather than a simple substitution, there isn’t a single value of $k\in\Bbb N-\{0\}$ for which, subsequently, the limit for $t$ to an arbitrary $x\in\Bbb N-\{0\}$ would give a not solvable undetermined form; you can prove me wrong finding one.

So, the problem of finding the sum still stands unchanged.